# Kendo popup template fullscreen

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

It is possible to make kendo template popup when add/edit in a full screen or maximize mode based on size of the screen?

I try using css, but still not perfectly fullscreen (contain scoll)

```
.k-widget.k-window {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}
.k-edit-form-container{
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EPIpuwex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust popup window through `editable.window` field of kendoGrid. To make popup full screen you should call `window.maximise()` method.

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          editable: {
            mode:"popup",
            template: $("#template").html(),
            window:{
              open: function (e){
                e.sender.maximize();
              }
            } 
          },

       ...
```